# Посчитать значение всех input type="time"

Tags: javascript, jquery

помогите посчитать значения всех input.
Пробовал преобразовать значение инпут  с помощью parseInt, считает некорректно.

И еще , нужно чтобы результат был в секундах , например 180 секунд, а не 3 мин.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $enterTime = $('.js-time-interview');
  $enterTimeLeng = $enterTime.length;
  $sum = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < $enterTimeLeng; i++) {

    $sum += parseInt($enterTime[i].value);
    
  }
  
  console.log($sum);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="js-time-interview" type="time" value="01:00">
<input class="js-time-interview" type="time" value="00:30">
<input class="js-time-interview" type="time" value="00:25">
<input class="js-time-interview" type="time" value="01:30">
```

Comment: а если значение будет час и больше ? Будет ли value "1:00:01" например ? :) Или это и так в часах и минутах ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $enterTime = $('.js-time-interview');
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < $enterTime.length; i++) {
    var valueArr = $enterTime[i].value.split(':').map((item) => {
      return +item;
    });

    sum += (valueArr[0] * 60 + valueArr[1]) * 60;
  }

  console.log(sum);

});
```

Ну, или совсем по модному

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $enterTime = $('.js-time-interview');

  var sum = [].reduce.call($enterTime, (prev, input) => {

    var valueArr = input.value.split(':').map((item) => {
      return +item;
    });

    return prev += (valueArr[0] * 60 + valueArr[1]) * 60;

  }, 0)

  console.log(sum);

});
```

Да, совсем забыл, у JQuery есть метод each().

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sum = 0;

  $('.js-time-interview').each(function(){
    var valueArr = $(this).val().split(':').map((item) => {
      return +item;
    });

    sum += (valueArr[0] * 60 + valueArr[1]) * 60;
  });

  console.log(sum);

});
```

Выбирайте, что душе угодно.

Comment: раз уж используете jQuery, я бы воспользовался `$.each`  :)

Comment: JQuery не пользуюсь достаточно давно, поэтому не сразу его возможности вспоминаю. )